# Why use Audience instead of Scopes with App Engine Cloud Endpoints from Android?

Tags: android, python, google-app-engine, oauth, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm developing an app for Android that uses Cloud Endpoints (Python) with Google Accounts as authentication. I've got everything set up pretty nicely, it all works great from the API Explorer, I've managed to generate the Gradle client library and use it in Android Studio, ...

Problem I have/had is this: When authenticating from Android using Audience (as the guide says) I can't get requests to complete. The oauth Bearer token App Engine receives is huge (over 800 characters) and my logs shows this message: Oauth framework user didn't match oauth token user. The audience I used is correct, when I enter a typo in the audience Google refuses to give me a token in the first place. If I authenticate using scopes (only replacing GoogleAccountCredential.usingAudience with .usingOAuth2) everything works fine and I get a 'regular', shorter token.

What am I doing wrong that results in the huge tokens when using the Audience, and why should I be using Audience instead of scopes in the first place?

Server code:

```
API = endpoints.api(
    name='apiDaycare',
    version='v1',
    description='API for Appy Daycare',
    audiences=['--WEB CLIENT ID HERE--'],
    scopes=[endpoints.EMAIL_SCOPE, 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login'],
    allowed_client_ids=[endpoints.API_EXPLORER_CLIENT_ID, '--Android app client ID here--', '--web client ID here'],
    canonical_name='Appy Daycare API',
    owner_name='Ambroos Vaes',
    title='Appy Daycare API',
    auth_level=AUTH_LEVEL.REQUIRED)
```

App code:

```
private void LoginTest(String accountName) {
    GoogleAccountCredential credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingAudience(this, Constants.AUDIENCE);
    credential.setSelectedAccountName(accountName);
    AppyDaycareAPI.Builder builder = new AppyDaycareAPI.Builder(
            AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), new AndroidJsonFactory(), credential
    );
    builder.setApplicationName("Appy Daycare Android");
    AppyDaycareAPI service = builder.build();
    TempTestTask task = new TempTestTask(this, service, credential);
    task.execute();
}

private class TempTestTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ModelsUsersAccountMessage> {

    private final Context context;
    private final AppyDaycareAPI service;
    private final GoogleAccountCredential credential;
    public TempTestTask(Context context, AppyDaycareAPI service, GoogleAccountCredential credential) {
        this.context = context;
        this.credential = credential;
        this.service = service;
    }

    protected ModelsUsersAccountMessage doInBackground(Void... unused) {
        Log.d("Account API test", "Token:");
        Log.d("Account API test", credential.getToken());
        ModelsUsersAccountMessage result = null;
        result = service.account().echo().execute();
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ModelsUsersAccountMessage modelsUsersAccountMessage) {
        Log.d("Account API test", modelsUsersAccountMessage.toPrettyString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Ever make progress on this?